# Linq Select on dynamic List of Object c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

Hello I am working on asp.net mvc project
and call an Api which return  List now I need to select some object from the list based on requirement but I am unable to use linq select because it is not working which dyamic.

**Code Api Get List**

```
List<dynamic> allblogswithuser = getallBlogs();
ViewData["AuthorBlogs"] = allblogswithuser.Where(a => a.postBlogType == "2").ToList();
```

The second line fails due to this

**Screen shot:**
[image]

**Api Call**

```
private List<dynamic> getallBlogs()
{
    try
    {
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseUri);

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            // httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            //httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30.0);
            var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(string.Format("api/client/getAllBlogs")).Result;

            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<dynamic>>(response);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {

        return null;
    }

}  //api get
```

**Json**

> {"user": {
>     "userID": 1234,
>     "userCode": "89-3ABC",
>     "biography": "good bio                                                                                            ",
>     "visitorCode": null,
>     "publicName": "test@test.com",
>     "firstName": " change",
>     "lastName": "isgood",
>     "userTypeID": 1,
>     "address1": "-",
>     "address2": "-",
>     "nationalIdentity": "-",
>     "city": "-",
>     "state": null,
>     "country": "-",
>     "DOB": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
>     "gender": null,
>     "emailID": "test@test.com",
>     "phoneNumber": "0",
>     "mobileNumber": null,
>     "faxNumber": null,
>     "bestTimeCall": null,
>     "title": null,
>     "alternateEmailID": null,
>     "zipCode": null,
>     "isRegister": true,
>     "websitesID": 3,
>     "extra1": "TEST",
>     "extra2": null,
>     "extra3": "test@test.com",
>     "IsActive": true,
>     "createDate": "2018-05-04T07:11:38.997",
>     "createBy": null,
>     "modifiedDate": null,
>     "modifiedBy": null,
>     "Timestamp": "AAAAAAAAHwE=",
>     "standardTime": "GMT Standard Time",
>     "profileImage": ".png",
>     "properEmail": null,
>     "headerImage": "user-bg.jpg",
>     "verifiedUser": false,
>     "occupation": "good occ",
>     "officeAddress": null,
>     "companyName": null
>   }}

and

> {
>     "blogs": {
>       "postID": 103,
>       "postBlogType": "1                                                                                                   ",
>       "blogImage": ".jpg",
>       "slug": "an-odyssey-in-the-thal-desert",
>       "title": "An odyssey in the Thal desert",
>       "postContent": "
>
> I’ve always been fascinated by the desert. The idea of a giant land of distant horizons, framed by a flawless canopy of blue sky, and complete silence. In my mind, being in a desert is like existing in a vacuum — no beginning, no end, and nothing around but space. A perfect, silent void. Few people appreciate the sheer beauty of a desert — far from the barren wastelands that we imagine them to be, they are dramatic, almost spiritual places, filled with life. Being from Australia, I had experienced deserts long before visiting Pakistan. My native country, an entire continent, is filled with deserts which in some cases stretch thousands of kilometres to the seashore.
>
> ",
>       "createDate": null,
>       "publishDate": "2018-05-04T12:30:52",
>       "userID": 1234,
>       "categoryID": 22,
>       "isShow": false,
>       "isApproved": false,
>       "websiteID": 6,
>       "miniPostContent": "
>
> test
>
> ",
>       "modifedDate": "2018-05-04T12:31:46.237",
>       "pageTitle": "test",
>       "pageKeyword": "tset",
>       "pageDescribtion": "test",
>       "Tags": [
>         ""
>       ],
>       "CombinedTags": ""
>     },
>     "user": {
>       "userID": 1234,
>       "userCode": "8124-ABC",
>       "biography": "good bio                                                                                            ",
>       "visitorCode": null,
>       "publicName": "test@test.com",
>       "firstName": " change",
>       "lastName": "isgood",
>       "userTypeID": 1,
>       "address1": "-",
>       "address2": "-",
>       "nationalIdentity": "-",
>       "city": "-",
>       "state": null,
>       "country": "-",
>       "DOB": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
>       "gender": null,
>       "emailID": "test@test.com",
>       "phoneNumber": "0",
>       "mobileNumber": null,
>       "faxNumber": null,
>       "bestTimeCall": null,
>       "title": null,
>       "alternateEmailID": null,
>       "zipCode": null,
>       "isRegister": true,
>       "websitesID": 3,
>       "extra1": "TEST",
>       "extra2": null,
>       "extra3": "test@test.com",
>       "IsActive": true,
>       "createDate": "2018-05-04T07:11:38.997",
>       "createBy": null,
>       "modifiedDate": null,
>       "modifiedBy": null,
>       "Timestamp": "AAAAAAAAHwE=",
>       "standardTime": "GMT Standard Time",
>       "profileImage": ".png",
>       "properEmail": null,
>       "headerImage": "user-bg.jpg",
>       "verifiedUser": false,
>       "occupation": "good occ",
>       "officeAddress": null,
>       "companyName": null
>     }
>   }

Please help.

Comment: Your screeshot only shows the input-data, but not the result you get. However if possible please don´t use images do show data, instead provide an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes the data in your text.

Comment: Based on the screen shot the result should be an empty list, unless you're getting a run time error.  What did you expect?

Comment: juharr i am expecting an object based on postBlogType is 1 and it is 1 i can see but failing.

Comment: I think you should add "Trim" method to postBlogType. In your case you have string '1 (multiple spaces)" so comparision will fail. 

```
 allblogswithuser.Where(a => a.postBlogType.Trim() == "2").ToList();
```

Comment: So when you´re looking for `1`, why does your query select only those that have `postBlogType == "2"`?

Comment: actually the result is join of two tables.

Comment: Try this `allblogswithuser.Where(a => a.postBlogType.Trim() == "2").ToList();`

Comment: Also it looks like `postBlogType` is a property on the `blogs` property.  Maybe you need `a => a.blogs.postBlogType.Trim() == "2"` instead?

Comment: @juharr yup i missed that. Correction made.

Comment: Honestly you'd be so much better off if you would map the json to a DTO class so you can can get compile time type checking.

Comment: it does not work juhar

Comment: @UsbHacker Can you post you JSON output?

Comment: elegant see now

Comment: Why two separate JSON objects? It should be a single object.

Comment: Suggestion:  I would put forth the extra effort and make concrete objects and let the ```JsonConvert``` give you a list of those objects.  It's not that hard unless you're in a situation where the objects returned are always unknown.  The order and mapping isn't as important but if you're in a situation where you never know what the object may be (meaning, you couldn't write a concrete type ever) then you're going to have to do without linq (for the most part) and write some custom code to decipher the dynamic types.